# Parallel mapM on Repa arrays

Tags: arrays, haskell, parallel-processing, repa

In my recent [work](https://github.com/bgamari/mixture-model) with `Gibbs sampling`, I've been making great use of the [`RVar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/rvar/0.2.0.1/doc/html/Data-RVar.html) which, in my view, provides a near ideal interface to random number generation.  Sadly, I've been unable to make use of Repa due to the inability to use monadic actions in maps.

While clearly monadic maps can't be parallelized in general, it seems to me that `RVar` may be at least one example of a monad where effects can be safely parallelized (at least in principle; I'm not terribly familiar with the inner workings of `RVar`). Namely, I want to write something like the following,

```
drawClass :: Sample -> RVar Class
drawClass = ...

drawClasses :: Array U DIM1 Sample -> RVar (Array U DIM1 Class)
drawClasses samples = A.mapM drawClass samples
```

where `A.mapM` would look something like,

```
mapM :: ParallelMonad m => (a -> m b) -> Array r sh a -> m (Array r sh b)
```

While clearly how this would work depends crucially on the implementation of `RVar` and its underlying `RandomSource`, in principle one would think that this would involve drawing a new random seed for each thread spawned and proceeding as usual.

Intuitively, it seems that this same idea might generalize to some other monads.

So, my question is: Could one construct a class `ParallelMonad` of monads for which effects can be safely parallelized (presumably inhabited by, at the least, `RVar`)?

What might it look like? What other monads might inhabit this class? Have others considered the possibility of how this might work in Repa?

Finally, if this notion of parallel monadic actions can't be generalized, does anyone see any nice way to make this work in the specific case of `RVar` (where it would be very useful)? Giving up `RVar` for parallelism is a very difficult trade-off.

Comment: I guess the sticking point is "drawing a new random seed for each thread spawned" -- how should this step work, and how should the seeds be merged again once all the threads return?

Comment: The RVar interface would almost certainly need some additions to accommodate spawning a new generator with a given seed. Admittedly, it's unclear how the mechanics of this work and it does seem quite `RandomSource` specific. My naive attempt at drawing a seed would be to do something simple and likely very wrong such as draw a vector of elements (in the case of `mwc-random`) and add 1 to each element to produce a seed for the first worker, add 2 for the second worker, etc. Woefully inadequate if you need cryptographic-quality entropy; hopefully fine if you just need a random walk.

Comment: I have been able to do something similar to what you're asking for using `fillChunkedIOP`.

Comment: I've come across this question while trying to solve a similar problem. I'm using MonadRandom and System.Random for monadic random computations in parallel. This is only possible with System.Random's `split` function. It has the disadvantage of producing different results (due to the nature of `split` but it does work. However, I'm trying to extend this to Repa arrays and not having much luck. Have you made any progress with this or is it a dead-end?

Comment: Monad without sequencing and dependencies between computations sounds more like applicative to me.

Comment: I am hesitant. As Tom Savage notes, `split` provides a necessary foundation, but note the comment on the source for how `split` is implemented: "-- no statistical foundation for this!". I incline to think that any method of splitting a PRNG will leave exploitable correlation between its branches, but do not have the statistical background to prove that.

Regarding the general question, I am not certain that

Answer (score 8):

It's been 7 years since this question has been asked, and it still seems like no-one came up with a good solution to this problem. Repa doesn't have a `mapM`/`traverse` like function, even one that could run without parallelization. Moreover, considering the amount of progress there was in the last few years it seems unlikely that it will happen either.

Because of stale state of many array libraries in Haskell and my overall dissatisfaction with their feature sets I've put forth a couple of years of work into an array library [`massiv`](https://github.com/lehins/massiv), which borrows some concepts from Repa, but takes it to a completely different level. Enough with the intro.

Prior to today, there was three monadic map like functions in `massiv` (not counting the synonym like functions: `imapM`, `forM` et al.):

- [`mapM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv-0.3.4.0/docs/Data-Massiv-Array.html#v:mapM) - the usual mapping in an arbitrary `Monad`. Not parallelizable for obvious reasons and is also a bit slow (along the lines of usual `mapM` over a list slow)
- [`traversePrim`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv-0.3.4.0/docs/Data-Massiv-Array.html#v:traversePrim) - here we are restricted to `PrimMonad`, which is significantly faster than `mapM`, but the reason for this is not important for this discussion.
- [`mapIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv-0.3.4.0/docs/Data-Massiv-Array.html#v:mapIO) - this one, as name suggests, is restricted to `IO` (or rather `MonadUnliftIO`, but that is irrelevant). Because we are in `IO` we can automatically split array in as many chunks as there are cores and use separate worker threads to map the `IO` action over each element in those chunks. Unlike pure `fmap`, which is also parallelizable, we have to be in `IO` here because of non-determinism of scheduling combined with side effects of our mapping action.

So, once I read this question, I thought to myself that the problem is practically solved in `massiv`, but no so fast. Random number generators, such as in [`mwc-random`](https://www.stackage.org/package/mwc-random) and others in [`random-fu`](https://www.stackage.org/package/random-source) can't use the same generator across many threads. Which means, that the only piece of the puzzle I was missing was: "drawing a new random seed for each thread spawned and proceeding as usual". In other words, I needed two things:

- A function that would initialize as many generators as there gonna be worker threads
- and an abstraction that would seamlessly give the correct generator to the mapping function depending on which thread that the action is running in.

So that is exactly what I did.

First I will give examples using the specially crafted [`randomArrayWS`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv-0.3.4.0/docs/Data-Massiv-Array.html#v:randomArrayWS) and [`initWorkerStates`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv-0.3.4.0/docs/Data-Massiv-Core.html#v:initWorkerStates) functions, as they are more relevant to the question and later move to the more general monadic map. Here are their type signatures:

```hs
randomArrayWS ::
     (Mutable r ix e, MonadUnliftIO m, PrimMonad m)
  => WorkerStates g -- ^ Use `initWorkerStates` to initialize you per thread generators
  -> Sz ix -- ^ Resulting size of the array
  -> (g -> m e) -- ^ Generate the value using the per thread generator.
  -> m (Array r ix e)
```

```hs
initWorkerStates :: MonadIO m => Comp -> (WorkerId -> m s) -> m (WorkerStates s)
```

For those who are not familiar with `massiv`, the [`Comp`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv-0.3.4.0/docs/Data-Massiv-Core.html#t:Comp) argument is a computation strategy to use, notable constructors are:

- `Seq` - run computation sequentially, without forking any threads
- `Par` - spin up as many threads as there are capabilities and use those to do the work.

I'll use [`mwc-random`](https://www.stackage.org/package/mwc-random) package as an example initially and later move to `RVarT`:

```hs
λ> import Data.Massiv.Array
λ> import System.Random.MWC (createSystemRandom, uniformR)
λ> import System.Random.MWC.Distributions (standard)
λ> gens <- initWorkerStates Par (\_ -> createSystemRandom)
```

Above we initialized a separate generator per thread using system randomness, but we could have just as well used a unique per thread seed by deriving it from the [`WorkerId`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scheduler-1.4.0/docs/Control-Scheduler.html#t:WorkerId) argument, which is a mere `Int` index of the worker. And now we can use those generators to create an array with random values:

```hs
λ> randomArrayWS gens (Sz2 2 3) standard :: IO (Array P Ix2 Double)
Array P Par (Sz (2 :. 3))
  [ [ -0.9066144845415213, 0.5264323240310042, -1.320943607597422 ]
  , [ -0.6837929005619592, -0.3041255565826211, 6.53353089112833e-2 ]
  ]
```

By using `Par` strategy the [`scheduler`](https://github.com/lehins/haskell-scheduler) library will split evenly the work of generation among available workers and each worker will use it's own generator, thus making it thread safe. Nothing prevents us from reusing the same `WorkerStates` arbitrary number of times as long as it is not done concurrently, which otherwise would result in an exception:

```hs
λ> randomArrayWS gens (Sz1 10) (uniformR (0, 9)) :: IO (Array P Ix1 Int)
Array P Par (Sz1 10)
  [ 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 7, 6, 0, 8, 8 ]
```

Now putting `mwc-random` to the side we can reuse the same concept for other possible uses cases by using functions like `generateArrayWS`:

```hs
generateArrayWS ::
     (Mutable r ix e, MonadUnliftIO m, PrimMonad m)
  => WorkerStates s
  -> Sz ix --  ^ size of new array
  -> (ix -> s -> m e) -- ^ element generating action
  -> m (Array r ix e)
```

and `mapWS`:

```hs
mapWS ::
     (Source r' ix a, Mutable r ix b, MonadUnliftIO m, PrimMonad m)
  => WorkerStates s
  -> (a -> s -> m b) -- ^ Mapping action
  -> Array r' ix a -- ^ Source array
  -> m (Array r ix b)
```

Here is the promised example on how to use this functionality with [`rvar`](https://www.stackage.org/package/rvar), [`random-fu`](https://www.stackage.org/package/random-fu) and [`mersenne-random-pure64`](https://www.stackage.org/package/mersenne-random-pure64) libraries. We could have used `randomArrayWS` here as well, but for the sake of example let's say we already have an array with different `RVarT`s, in which case we need a `mapWS`:

```hs
λ> import Data.Massiv.Array
λ> import Control.Scheduler (WorkerId(..), initWorkerStates)
λ> import Data.IORef
λ> import System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64 as MT
λ> import Data.RVar as RVar
λ> import Data.Random as Fu
λ> rvarArray = makeArrayR D Par (Sz2 3 9) (\ (i :. j) -> Fu.uniformT i j)
λ> mtState <- initWorkerStates Par (newIORef . MT.pureMT . fromIntegral . getWorkerId)
λ> mapWS mtState RVar.runRVarT rvarArray :: IO (Array P Ix2 Int)
Array P Par (Sz (3 :. 9))
  [ [ 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 0, 3 ]
  , [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 6, 2 ]
  , [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7 ]
  ]
```

It is important to note, that despite the fact that pure implementation of Mersenne Twister is being used in the above example, we cannot escape the IO. This is because of the non-deterministic scheduling, which means that we never know which one of the workers will be handling which chunk of the array and consequently which generator will be used for which part of the array. On the up side, if the generator is pure and splittable, such as [`splitmix`](https://www.stackage.org/package/splitmix), then we can use the pure, deterministic and parallelizable generation function: [`randomArray`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv-0.3.4.0/docs/Data-Massiv-Array.html#v:randomArray), but that is already a separate story.

Comment: In case you'd like to see some benchmarks: https://alexey.kuleshevi.ch/blog/2019/12/21/random-benchmarks/

Answer (score 4):

It's probably not a good idea to do this due to inherently sequential nature of PRNGs. Instead, you might want to transition your code as follows:

1. Declare an IO function (`main`, or what have you).
2. Read as many random numbers as you need.
3. Pass the (now pure) numbers onto your repa functions.

Comment: Would it be possible to burn-in each PRNG in each parallel thread to create statistical independence?

Comment: @J.Abrahamson yes, it would be possible. See my answer.